# How to get Firefox bookmarks from a Delphi application?

Tags: delphi, firefox, sqlite

I know how to get the favourites from IE, but how can I access Firefox's bookmarks?

Here's the code I have for retrieving the IE favourites:

```
uses
  ShlObj, ActiveX;

function GetIEFavourites(const favpath: string): TStrings;
var
  searchrec: TSearchRec;
  str: TStrings;
  path, dir, FileName: string;
  Buffer: array[0..2047] of Char;
  found: Integer;
begin
  str := TStringList.Create;
  // Get all file names in the favourites path
  path  := FavPath + '\*.url';
  dir   := ExtractFilepath(path);
  found := FindFirst(path, faAnyFile, searchrec);
  while found = 0 do
  begin
    // Get now URLs from files in variable files
    Setstring(FileName, Buffer, GetPrivateProfilestring('InternetShortcut',
      PChar('URL'), nil, Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer), PChar(dir + searchrec.Name)));
    str.Add(FileName);
    found := FindNext(searchrec);
  end;
  // find Subfolders
  found := FindFirst(dir + '\*.*', faAnyFile, searchrec);
  while found = 0 do
  begin
    if ((searchrec.Attr and faDirectory) > 0) and (searchrec.Name[1] <> '.') then
      str.Addstrings(GetIEFavourites(dir + '\' + searchrec.Name));
    found := FindNext(searchrec);
  end;
  FindClose(searchrec);
  Result := str;
end;

procedure FreePidl(pidl: PItemIDList);
var
  allocator: IMalloc;
begin
  if Succeeded(SHGetMalloc(allocator)) then
  begin
    allocator.Free(pidl);
    {$IFDEF VER100}
    allocator.Release;
    {$ENDIF}
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  pidl: PItemIDList;
  FavPath: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
begin
  if Succeeded(ShGetSpecialFolderLocation(Handle, CSIDL_FAVORITES, pidl)) then
  begin
    if ShGetPathfromIDList(pidl, FavPath) then
      ListBox1.Items := GetIEFavourites(StrPas(FavPath));
    // The calling application is responsible for freeing the PItemIDList-pointer
    // with the Shell's IMalloc interface
    FreePIDL(pidl);
  end;
end;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you realize Firefox bookmarks can be found in C:\Documents and Settings\user\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\asdkjfh.default\bookmarks.html

Comment: Maybe he didn't, Sinan. Please feel free to post an answer demonstrating how to get that file and then extract the bookmarks from it.

Answer (score 2):

The favorites are saved in 'places.sqlite' in the profile folder. They are in table **moz_bookmarks**. They refer to entries in table **moz_places** with their field **fk**. Get [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/) as dll and a delphi binding like [this one](http://www.itwriting.com/blog/a-simple-delphi-wrapper-for-sqlite-3).

Open the database with **SQLite3_Open** and use **SQLite3_Exec** to send ordinary sql statements to access the data, like

```
SELECT * FROM moz_bookmarks;
```

Unfortunately firefox locks places.sqlite, which means you have to copy it first (normal file copy). After you have worked on the copy you can delete it.

Comment: When I try using the sqlite3 command-line program, I am barred access to the places.sqlite file. It says the database is locked; I assume that's because Firefox is still running. Would other programs using the DLL likely have the same problem?

Comment: Yes, Firefox keeps a lock on the file, you need to copy it first and then work with the copy. You can copy it while Firefox is running.

Answer (score 1):

TBookmarks component from MetaProduct... it's $75.00 though:
http://www.metaproducts.com/mp/TBookmarks_component.htm

quote from their site:

For Borland Delphi 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2009.

New! FireFox 3, Safari and Google Chrome Bookmarks are supported!

MetaProducts TBookmarks is a Delphi 2 - 7, 2005-2009 component that helps you to display MS Internet Explorer Favorites (4.0 - 8.0,) MSN Explorer, Opera Hotlists (3.0 - 9.0) and Netscape, Safari, Chrome, FireFox and Mozilla Bookmarks (2.0 - 8.0) in a menu.

Simply drop the TBookmarks component on the form and assign its Menu property and OnURL event. Set Enabled to True to collect all bookmark information in the specified TMenuItem.

You can also use TTreeView component to make TBookmarks populate the entries there automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Firefox bookmarks are a HTML file stored in
`<WindowsUserPath`>\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\
`<aRamdonProfileName`>\bookmark.htm as Sinan Ünür said.

So you need to get the mozilla profiles dir and retrie the folder
name in there.

After that you need to parse the html file.....

So AFAIK, no, there's no API to directly get the FF bookmarks.